# Перенос Yii с openserver на centos?

Tags: yii, сервер, centos

Не могу понять чем отличаются локальные серверы от нормальных? На локалке все тип-топ. Переношу на центос, вылазит ошибка о неизвестной переменной. Как их сконфигурировать, чтобы они работали одинаково?

---

UPD

разница конечно в php.ini
чтобы сайт не падал из-за notice чую нужно html_errors выставить в off ?
или display_errors поменять?

---

заработало.
 пришлось проверочку сделать

```
'value' => '($data->id_dep) ? $data->idDep->name : ""',
```

но я как понимаю трабла в том что даже замечания ложат сайт. может уровень угрозы повыше поставить?

Comment: По сути ничем не отличаются, если какая-то переменная неизвестная, значит надо просто найти эту переменную и понять почему она не определена. Возможно на "нормальном" сервере запрещены глобальные переменные, возможно перенесли коряво. Причин много. Но все те же самые ошибки можно получить и на "локальном" сервере, если его настроить аналогично "нормальному" и при переносе допустить те же самые ошибки. Для этого и существуют различные тесты: unit-тесты, функциональные, интеграционные и т.д. Но для начала неплохо бы научиться отлаживать код - хотя бы понять почему переменная не определена

Comment: phpinfo(); и смотрите чем отличается. Как вариант, ошибку вы можете видеть потому что включен display_errors, и зависит от того какой error_reporting указан

Comment: "но я как понимаю трабла в том что даже замечания ложат сайт" - трабла в том, что вы игнорировали замечание при разработке, и теперь их надо отключить еще и при деплойменте. По-хорошему, конечно, они и так там должны быть отключены (только логироваться), но отключенные варнинги при разработке практически гарантируют их наличие в конечном продукте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо у вас отличаются версии PHP и/или конфиги php(php.ini). На локальных машинах лучше всегда включать все предупреждения и notice в конфиге.
Советую для предотвращения таких ошибок использовать lint-утилиты. Для разных IDE они разные. Это проще, чем unit-тесты, о которых говорит @BOPOH, но позволит уловить большинство опечаток и сэкономит нервы.

Comment: Сравнивать (а тем более заменять) тесты и lint - по меньшей мере глупо - у них разные цели. Сомневаюсь, что lint определит использование глобальных переменных, равно как и ошибку в `function a($a) { return $a; } a();`. Он только проверяет синтаксические ошибки, но раз локально код работает, значит ошибка не в синтаксисе, а логике.

Comment: Глобальные переменые - зло.
Да и не сравниваю я lint и тесты. Они для разного служат. Но в данном контексте спасли бы кучу времени.

Comment: Вы еще раз прочитайте вопрос - на локальном хосте все работает. Что бы показал линт, если это работает? Ничего бы не показал. Глобальные переменные я привел во-первых, как пример того, что линт ошибку здесь не показал бы, но проблема бы была. А во-вторых, вполне вероятно что код работает дома, но не работает где-то именно из-за этого. Кучу времени в данной ситуации спасло бы умение отлаживать код (я уж не говорю про CI и прочее)

Comment: Изначально речь шла о том, что вылезла ошибка про неизвестную переменную. Линтеры это показывают на лету и предупреждают об этом.

Comment: Не надо придумывать. Вопрос изначально был: "На локалке все тип-топ. Переношу на центос, вылазит ошибка о неизвестной переменной." Пример, когда переменная будет неизвестной, но линтер этого не покажет я уже привел. Поэтому на моем примере ваш ответ точно бы не помог